# Android.mk rules to build .ko

Tags: android, netfilter

I tried to make a kernel module with netfilter, and use `insmod` to insert it into my android kernel.
But I can't find the rule to make it under Android context. Please help me and thank you.

Comment: I want to do something similar. It looks like there no rule/target using Android.mk. A work-around might be to kick-off a "conventional" make from within the Android.mk. Any ideas on how to do this?